# How to configure IDA to load .pdb files from Microsoft public symbol server?

Tags: ida, windbg, symbols, debugging-symbols

I've done this in one VM but I can't seem to replicate it in another. I'm using IDA to analyze a 32-bit Windows PE file. I then want to step thru it with a WinDbg debugger from within IDA.

So when I begin debugging it:

[image]

And break on a breakpoint, I want to load symbols, say for cmtcmt32.dll:

[image]

But instead of loading them it gives me this "Choose PDB file" window:

[image]

How do I set it up to load it from the Microsoft public symbol server?

PS. I tried running the following commands:

```
.sympath srv*c:symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
.reload /f
```

But it doesn't do anything. It just shows a bunch of errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding the windbg sympath, you are supplying an invalid path (missing the backslash after `c:`), should be: `.sympath srv*c:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

Comment: @joshpoley: Hmm. I tried it with the slash like you showed, then did `.reload /f comctl32.dll` and still got `*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.23403_none_2b180b30457f196c\COMCTL32.dll`

Comment: At that point be sure to turn on `!sym noisy` and look for more detailed error information.

Comment: @joshpoley [Here's what I'm getting.](https://i.imgur.com/NkJZC1B.png) I'm running it on Windows 7. I don't use WinDgb that much. What's going on there?

Comment: I agree theres not much useful in that output, though it looks like it isn't resolving https:// as a web request, you could try switching to http to see if that helps, or ensure you are running the latest build of windbg.
It also looks like you are using the 64-bit version of windbg against a 32-bit dump or process, use the 32-bit version of windbg instead (though this is likely unrelated to symbol resolution issues).

Answer (score 5):

It seems IDA recognizes _NT_SYMBOL_PATH so all you only need to is:

1. Start -> RUN -> RUNDLL32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
2. Under "System variables", add an entry named "_NT_SYMBOL_PATH" and set its value like SRV*\C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
3. The next time you launch IDA, it should tell you when to load MS symbols from the symbols store.

PS: you may need to install VC Redistribute libraries if IDA prompts an error.

Comment: `SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` worked for me

Comment: For Chromium, do `SRV*https://chromium-browser-symsrv.commondatastorage.googleapis.com`